# Smart Contract States

Tags: contract-development, state-transition, state

I have been encountering the word 'state' in a lot of research papers, and I was wondering what they exactly mean by the **state of the smart contract**. I am aware of the following [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17456/what-does-it-mean-by-smart-contract-state-where-they-get-stored); however, it only describes the meaning of state change.

What does it store, and where is it stored?

Comment: Solidity contract state variables are like C++ class member variables.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike other forms of software in which the data is (generally) external to the software that manages it, contract data is stored within a namespace (a key/value store) that is logically "inside" the contract itself.

At a protocol level addresses (including contracts) have balances. Contracts also have code. That code will lay out data organization within its own namespace. All three are included in the idea of "state." In this context, it could be described as the condition or just the data.

Consider this simple, contrived contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.16;

contract State {

    uint256 public someVal;

    function set(uint v) public payable {
        someVal = v;
    }
}
```

There is a getter function (`public`) and it will return `someVal`. There is a function that can update it AND accept ether. So, there is a `uint` stored in the contract, and the contract has a balance that is not necessarily zero. Additionally, the address where the contract bytecode is deployed has code.

All three are established by processing transactions and computing the "state" of the chain.

BTW, we could restrict the allowable state transitions with something like:

`require(v > 100, "no small numbers, please.");`

That would be in addition to protocol-level restrictions such as not sending more money than one actually has.

In case you are interested in how it is laid out, here is an over-simplified summary. The compiler will read `someVal` and assign it "slot 0" because it was first. The EVM will compute (pseudo) a key with `hash(contractAddress,0)`. Including the contract address in the hash prevents collisions with other contracts. The key provides a logical location in which to store a 32-byte word (the value). The "State" can be understood as a key/value store where all the contracts manage their own variables as they see fit and the protocol looks after protocol-level concerns such as balances.

As you consider that, keep in mind it is a logical description and doesn't include the Merkle/Patricia tries that help with organization and validation and it is silent on the issues of physical storage, indexing, caching strategies, light client implementations and other client-side implementation concerns.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of “state” is the position the smart contract has in the space described by its permanent variables.

In the case the smart contract has one bool variable and nothing more, it can assume two states.

In the case it has two bool variables and nothing more, it can assume four states (00-01-11-10).

If it should have one uint variable it has 2^256 states.

And so on.

If each possible state is defined as a single point in the variables space, the smart contract move from one point to another point each time its permanent variables assume new values and you can describe completely its state listing its internal permanent variables values. The possible trajectories depends from the code and some of them are not allowed.